# fibanocci series in php

Tags: php

i have created a following program to make fibanocci series in php

```
function find_max_paths_fib($spaces) {

    $c = array();
    $c[0] = 1;
    $c[1] = 1;

    for ($i = 2; $i <= $spaces; $i++) {
        if ($i >= 2) {
            echo $c[$i] = $c[$i-2] + $c[$i-1];
        }
    }

    return $c[$spaces];


}
```

$spaces denote up to how much number i need to generate the series, but find_max_paths_fib(8000) or for some large number returns **INF**, i have tried in c++ and got the same result. Is there any way to compute it? Or is my function wrong?

Comment: value of fibonacci(8000) is way out of integer range. it contains more than 1600 digits. check at this link for n = 8000 - http://php.bubble.ro/fibonacci/

Comment: how do they print those values? is there any library function? Since php variables need not be specified with data types i don't thing it is computed as integers

Comment: Try casting as float.  Are you on a 64b processor?

Comment: For such large numbers, primitive datatypes, even Double, wont work. String based multiplication techniques will have to be implemented.

Comment: @Joseph_J fibonacci(8000) is way out of any primitive datatype range

Comment: But the site you mentioned @MadhurBhaiya prints the value of 8000

Comment: @NaveenKingmaker they obviously are using some advanced code.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya Fair enough :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you must use [BC Math Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) or [GNU Multiple Precision](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) for working with large number

for install this module use flowing command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmath // set your php version 
#or sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath
#or sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmath
#or sudo apt-get install php-bcmath
```

or if use GNU Multiple Precision:

```
sudo apt-get install php70-gmp// set your php version 
#or sudo apt-get install php7.2-gmp
#or sudo apt-get install php7.1-gmp
#or sudo apt-get install php-gmp
```

if use microsoft windows: [link](http://php.net/manual/fa/install.windows.extensions.php)

after installation restart apache

Using BCMath:

```
$sum = bcadd('1234567812345678', '8765432187654321');

// $sum is now the string '9999999999999999'
print $sum;
```

Using GMP:

```
$sum = gmp_add('1234567812345678', '8765432187654321');

// $sum is now a GMP resource, not a string; use gmp_strval( ) to convert
print gmp_strval($sum);
```

final code :

```
function find_max_paths_fib2($spaces) {

    $c = array();
    $c[1] = 1;
    $c[2] = 1;

    for ($i = 3; $i <= $spaces; $i++) {
        if ($i >= 3) {
            echo $c[$i] = bcadd($c[$i-2] , $c[$i-1]);
        }
    }

    return $c[$spaces];


}
```

Comment: @NaveenKingmaker In this case, numerical computations will be made, such as the calculations of the strings

Comment: seems strange, http://php.bubble.ro/fibonacci/ this thing returns number starting with "2390......"  but my script returns starting with "3867...." , curious to know about why this difference is occuring ( i supplied n=8181)

Comment: @NaveenKingmaker we start n from 0 ! ```$c[0] = 1;``` 8181 in we code is equal to 8082 in http://php.bubble.ro/fibonacci/

Comment: n is (index of $c) +1

Comment: I edited my answer!
Test the new function (find_max_paths_fib2)

Comment: got it, awesome.I was wrong, there is only slight increase in time for processing (may be milli seconds, i couldnt find the difference), those libraries processed the data faster